# Simplest Java chart library?

Tags: java

Could someone please recommend a simple (as in very easy to understand) charting library for Java?

I just want to add a simple chart into my program and figured I might save some time by learning a library.

Comment: Is it going to end up in a web page or a e.g. Swing UI?

Comment: In a desktop type application.  (Swing UI)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is one of the best open source charting packages for java.

Answer (score 2):

A litte outdated, but still working and with free documentation (JFreeChart has just the API for free, the devguide is saled) is [jCharts](http://jcharts.sourceforge.net).

A sample code for Swing is available [here](http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/userGuide/exportingImages.html#Charts+In+Swing+Apps), if you don't need anything fancy or special it may be easier than JFreeChart because of the direct available documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is definitely the way to go. Although the (for-sale) manual is useful if you're doing a huge amount of work using this, it's instructive in the first instance to check out this huge selection of [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/CatalogChart.htm) (screenshots and code). That will get you 90% of what you need.