# How to draw sin graph?

Tags: java, user-interface

how to draw graphic of this math function?

Comment: The problem is the graph-drawing, I take it, not the sin? Which [UI framework are you using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087013/java-gui-frameworks-which-are-out-there) - Swing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest Java chart library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384276/simplest-java-chart-library)

Comment: i dont know how to get the coords to draw this graph(

Comment: If he needs to draw a sin graph then it's probably for a UI programming exercise - I doubt he wants a charting library.

Comment: Sounds like you don't know much about the sine function.  Try 0 <= x <= 2*pi for the x-axis; the y-axis ranges from -1 <= y <= +1.

Comment: Please post how far you got and where you got stuck, then we can probably help. Otherwise your question will probably be closed, because it is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont know how to get the coords to
>   draw this graph

Depending on this comment, I assume you can draw `(x,y)` coordinates, so this is not your problem, but rather to find `y` for a given `x` so the resulting graph is a sine.

Well the simplest case is `y = sin(x)`. This unscaled version will have a period of 2*Pi = 6.283.. and `y` will have values between -1 and 1. You can, however, scale the graph, so this becomes:

```
// scale_x and scale_y are floating point numbers, 1.0 = original scale
y = sin(x / scale_x) * scale_y;
```

Answer (score 1):

See the example included in your JDK: `JAVA_HOME`\demo\applets\SimpleGraph